# Correct way to restart or shutdown the stream using UncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a stream app with below driver code for real-time message transformation.

```java
String topicName = ...
KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream(topicName);

source.transform(() -> new MyTransformer()).to(...);

KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, appConfig);
streams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        logger.error("UncaughtExceptionHandler " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
});


streams.cleanUp();
streams.start();

Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new  Thread(streams::close));
```

After few minutes of execution, app throws the below exception and then not progressing through the stream.

```
[2017-02-22 14:24:35,139] ERROR [StreamThread-14] User provided listener org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$1 for group TRANSFORMATION-APP failed on partition assignment (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: task [0_11] Error while creating the state manager
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.<init>(AbstractTask.java:72)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.createStreamTask(StreamThread.java:633)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addStreamTasks(StreamThread.java:660)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.access$100(StreamThread.java:69)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$1.onPartitionsAssigned(StreamThread.java:124)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:228)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:313)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:277)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:259)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1013)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:979)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:407)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:242)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: task [0_11] Failed to lock the state directory: /tmp/kafka-streams/TRANSFORMATION-APP/0_11
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.<init>(ProcessorStateManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.<init>(AbstractTask.java:69)
    ... 13 more
```

I tried to flush out the `/tmp/kafka-streams/TRANSFORMATION-APP` directory and restarted the app but again throws the same exception. One thing I noticed was that app works fine until it transforms all backlog messages but throws exception after processing some of the new messages!

Sometimes it also throws the below uncaught exceptions.

```
[ERROR] 2017-02-22 12:40:54.804 [StreamThread-29] MyTransformer - UncaughtExceptionHandler task directory [/tmp/kafka-streams/TRANSFORMATION-APP/0_24] doesn't exist and couldn't be created

[ERROR] 2017-02-22 12:42:30.148 [StreamThread-179] MyTransformer - UncaughtExceptionHandler stream-thread [StreamThread-179] Failed 
to rebalance
```

After throwing (one of) these exceptions, app is still running but not progressing through the stream.

What is the correct way to handle these errors?. Is it possible to restart the stream programmatically, without killing the app? This app is under [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/). At at worst case, I would prefer to terminate the app properly (without any message loss), so that monit can restart it.

The input topic has 100 partitions and I have set `num.stream.threads` to 100 in the app configuration. The app is on `Kafka 0.10.1.1-cp1.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kakfa `0.10.1.x` has some bugs with regard to multi threading. You can either upgrade to `0.10.2` (AK released today, CP 3.2 should follow shortly) or you apply the following workaround:

- use single thread execution only
- if you need more thread, start more instances
- for each instance, configure a different state directory

You might also need to delete your local state directory (only once) before restarting to get into a overall consistent application state.

In any case, there will be no data loss. Kafka Streams guarantees at-least-once processing semantics even in case of failure. This applies to you local stores too -- after you delete local state dir, on startup those state will be recreated from the underlying Kafka changelog topics (it an expensive operation though).

The `UncaughtExceptionHandler` does only provide you a way to figure out that a thread died. It does not (directly) help to restart your application. To recover died threads, you need to close `KafkaStreams` instance completely and create/start a new one. We hope to add better support for this in the future.

Comment: Thanks. I restarted the app with single thread. It was running fine for a while but throws `failed to rebalance` exception which was caught in the `UncaughtExceptionHandler `. To resolve that I have increased the rebalance.backoff.ms and zookeeper.session.timeout.ms parameters for internal producer/consumer. Now it seems running fine!

Comment: As a follow up, is there any best practices to follow for closing the stream instance completely? I use `streams::close` before start the stream in my `UncaughtExceptionHandler'. I don't the consequences..

Comment: That's ok. You should only no call `streams::close` at the same time by two threads -- this might deadlock. Otherwise, it's fine to close in exception handler.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax If it should not be called by more than one thread at a time, then why not make it synchronized in the `KafkaStreams` class (just asking!)

Comment: There is an update to this question at: https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/error-handling/kstreams.html

Answer (score 4):

I understand that this question was asked far ago, but will post update about new Kafka-Streams feature. Since `Kafka-Streams` `2.8.0`, you have the ability to automatically replace failed stream thread (that caused by uncaught exception)
using `KafkaStreams` method `void setUncaughtExceptionHandler(StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler eh);` with `StreamThreadExceptionResponse.REPLACE_THREAD`. With that, failed message will be reprocessed on new replaced stream.
For more details please take a look at [Kafka Streams Specific Uncaught Exception Handler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-671%3A+Introduce+Kafka+Streams+Specific+Uncaught+Exception+Handler)

```
kafkaStreams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(ex -> {
    log.error("Kafka-Streams uncaught exception occurred. Stream will be replaced with new thread", ex);
    return StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler.StreamThreadExceptionResponse.REPLACE_THREAD;
});
```

Prior to `Kafka-Streams` `2.8.0`, you can implement logic of restarting failed KafkaStreams by your own. The idea is like the following:

```
KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = createYourKafkaStreams();
kafkaStreams.setStateListener(createErrorStateListener(sourceTopicName, kafkaStreams));

private KafkaStreams.StateListener createErrorStateListener(String sourceTopicName, KafkaStreams kafkaStreams) {
    return (newState, oldState) -> {
        if (newState == KafkaStreams.State.ERROR) {
            log.error("Kafka Stream is in ERROR state for source topic [{}]", sourceTopicName);
            replaceFailedKafkaStream(kafkaStreams, sourceTopicName);
        }
    };
}

// invoke this method either right after stream died, or by scheduling
private void replaceFailedKafkaStream(KafkaStreams kafkaStreams, String sourceTopicName) {
    kafkaStreams.close();
    KafkaStreams newKafkaStreams = createYourKafkaStreams();
    newKafkaStreams.setStateListener(createErrorStateListener(sourceTopicName, newKafkaStreams));
    newKafkaStreams.start();
}
```