# How to close KStream if all brokers are not available

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am using Kstreams with SpringBoot Application. If the Kafka is closed or it is Unreachable, only following is locked:

> Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be
>   available.

I want to close the application or atleast log the Exception if such condition occurs. Is there any way to do the same.

Comment: by default spring kafka log all those exceptions right? correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Yes, that are logged on warn level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a CustomHealthIndicator that do the connection check continuously and if it found that the Kafka is unreachable it will throw exception and close the application.

Sample Code is here:

```
public class CustomHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {
    @Override
    public Health health() {
        return Health.up().withDetail("Status Code", "SUCCESS").build();
    }

    private void doHealthCheck() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, localhost:9092);
        AdminClient adminClient =  AdminClient.create(props);
        try {
            DescribeClusterOptions dco = new DescribeClusterOptions();
            dco.timeoutMs(30000);
            adminClient.describeCluster(dco).clusterId().get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.exit(-1);
        } finally {
            adminClient.close();
            adminClient = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add shutdown hook when such exception happen. May be possible duplicate of [Kafka Stream: Graceful shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322086/kafka-stream-graceful-shutdown)

Please [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50322901/585398)